# How to display app.config value to textbox?

Tags: c#, app-config

I have path name in App Setting Value. Now I want to display the path name on an text box in c#.but i dont have idea to do this. So please Help me.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` and its `AppSettings`:

```
textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"];
```

Change key from "Path" according to your configuration file.

Comment: Thank you.but i kept app config values in Class File. How can i call it.?

Comment: @PrabhagaranP What do you mean by app config values in Class File? Show the code or something else that could help me to understand you...